# Mailchimp API 3.0. Need to retrieve a specific template HTML

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

Am updating an the mailchimp API version form 1.2 -> 3.0
I am trying to retrieve a template HTML file.
But there are no methods to do this.

I could do this in ver 1.3 and 2.0
https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?output=json&method=templateInfo&apikey=XXX
returned the full html of the template.

Is there a way to do this?

Can connect to the API with no errors, just cannot get the full html for a template. I have noticed there are some other old answers here (few years ago), but does anyone have any new info.

I could do this in ver 1.3 and 2.0
https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?output=json&method=templateInfo&apikey=XXX&tid=280089
returned the full html of the template.

In ver 3.0 there is 
https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/templates/280089/default-content
does not return full html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can retrieve the HTML content from the Campaign that is using the template but not template itself.

Not sure why.  This would only work once a campaign is created but not on templates not used yet.  Strange behavior.

https://mailchimp.com/developer/api/marketing/campaign-content/get-campaign-content/